# Virtualbox: XP Setup Help

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Virtualbox for running Windows XP. Here is the problem:

I started the machine just fine. The setup loaded and the machine started setting up. But then it restarted automatically to let the setup load but it loaded the setup again! And I have to set it up again and again not even loading Windows XP. How do you solve this?

P.S. I installed it fine, but when I power off the machine and use it later, it loads the setup. Does this load Windows XP or do I have to set it up again?

-linuhackz

Comment: Did you try to disconnect (unmount) the installation media (CD/ISO file) from the virtual machine's options?

Comment: No i didnt do that and i did it without mounting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disconnect the virtual image of Windows XP. When you do not do this, the XP installation starts over again.

[image]

<sup>Source of the image - Internet.</sup>

Comment: _“Source of the image - Internet”_ Internet is not a single item, you should include a link at least.

Comment: Exactly. Provide us a link.